# Tmux not responding to commands in shell script

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a simple bash script that creates a new tmux session and does some layout:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
tmux new-session -s $1
tmux split-window -h -p 50 -t 1
tmux new-window
tmux split-window -h -p 50 -t 1
```

The contents are in an executable script. When i execute the script with the name of the session as the argument, I get a new tmux session but there is only one un-split window, instead of the two [split] windows that I am telling it to create. If I run the scripts one by one on the shell prompt then I do get the desired outcome. So why is this not working in the script?

Comment: See if an answer can be found here [**Tmux - Archlinux wiki**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that first command starts tmux and wait for it to finish before continue. What you need to do is write custom tmux.conf file and add pass it through `-f filename.conf` with first command.

the other possible way is use `tmux -d`

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s $1 
tmux split-window -h -p 50 -t $1
tmux new-window -t $1
tmux split-window -h -p 50 -t $1
tmux attach -t $1
```